# Resize canvas using fabric.js lanczos filter

Tags: fabricjs

I am a fabric.js novice, I have got through a great deal of documentation and code samples, but still can't figure out how can I achieve such simple goal.

I start from a DOM canvas, and would like to obtain a downsized canvas, using the lanczos filter.

```
var canvas = /* a DOM canvas, obtained through prior processing */
var width = /* target width, smaller than source canvas width */
var height = /* target height, smaller than source canvas height */
```

I create the filter:

```
var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Resize();
filter.resizeType = 'lanczos';
filter.LanczosLobes = 3;
```

I calculate the scaling:

```
var scalingX = width / canvas.width;
var scalingY = height / canvas.height;
```

Now it is not clear to me how can I apply the filter to the canvas, and get the downsized canvas.

Or could someone suggest another javascript library or function, as simple as possible, to perform a canvas-to-canvas lanczos downsize?

Comment: FabricJS would probably be a bit overkill if you're just looking for lanczos downscaling since Fabric's resizefilters are intended to be used for images within the canvas, not the canvas itself. You could try https://github.com/nodeca/pica if you're not needing any fabric's other functionality

Comment: Thank you, I had noticed pica, but their documentation says that the resize algorithm is not extremely accurate, due to the fact that they neglect gamma correction and perform 8-bit calculations. Their statement ends with "we don't recommend this library for resizing professional quality images". Shall I worry about this?

Comment: I could be wrong but my understanding is that gamma correction info being ignored is a limitation of canvas itself so it will probably be the same for any client-side solution. I haven't used pica extensively so I can't speak for how it compares to proper software resizing but I feel like it would be sufficient for most applications.